# Symfony FOSRest - Before action

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have implemented a FOSRestBundle to support REST calls.

Now I want to know how I can handle a "beforeAction" - Methode.

To check if the called function have a "@ReuireLogin" Annotation or not. And handle if the request doesn't include a session token.